# $ y = \frac{8}{\cos^2 x} + 18 \cdot\cos^2 x$ find the minimum possible value of y.

Tags: trigonometry, optimization

Given , $y = 8 \sec^2 x + 18 \cos^2 x$, find the minimum possible value of $y$.

Well, basically, it's a Question from Minimizing and Maximizing i.e. (Optimization) Section.

So, my try went as follows -

$ y = \frac{8}{\cos^2 x} + 18 \cdot\cos^2 x$

So, we we can see the value of cos function can't be $90$ degrees or $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Now, comes this part where I'm completely clueless,

If $x$ doesn't equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, then it must be reduced such that all functions change to cosine or sec, which here it seems impossible.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Recall that by AM-GM inequality

$$\frac{8}{\cos^2 x} + 18 \cos^2 x\ge 2\sqrt{144}=24$$

with equality for

$$\frac{8}{\cos^2 x} = 18 \cos^2 x$$

Comment: AM GM? what's it?

Comment: It is a “must known“ in math http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality

Comment: The problem would be more interesting with $8$ and $18$ switched.

Answer (score 3):

$$y = \frac{8}{\cos^2 x} + 18\cos^2 x= \left( \sqrt{18} \cos x -\frac{\sqrt{8}}{\cos x}\right)^2+24 \ge 24$$

Comment: Hi jaideep! how was advanced? Would you please come to this room: [pss](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies)

Comment: @samjoe Well it didn't go well as per my expectations. I am obtaining ~170 marks. BTW, I will probably go to BITS, Pilani, because my BITSAT score was 374, and I could probably get CS or EEE (Which will be better option, because with my marks in JEE, I'll not get CS/EE/ECE in Top 5 IITs)

Comment: Your bitsat score is v. nice! I got 344. Didn't check the advanced result as its all shuffled. Atb for the future!

Comment: @samjoe Thanks and All the Best to you too! BTW, you can check your marks by taking printout, because it's really frustrating to match each question my switching tabs and scrolling pages. BTW, you will get Mechanical in Pilani, so you can give a thought to it too!

Answer (score 0):

Using calculus:
$$\begin{align} y &= \frac{8}{\cos^2 x} + 18 \cdot\cos^2 x=8+8\tan^2x+18\cos^2x;\\
y'&=\frac{16\tan x}{\cos^2x}-36\cos x\sin x=0 \Rightarrow 16\sin x=36\cos^4x\sin x \Rightarrow \cos^2x=\frac23;\\
y''&=\frac{16+32\sin^2 x}{\cos^4x}+36\sin^2x-36\cos^2x=\\
& \ \ \ \ \ \frac{48-32\cos^2 x}{\cos^4x}+36-72\cos^2x=\\
& \ \ \ \ \ 60+36-48=48>0\end{align}$$
Hence:
$$y_{min}=\frac{8}{2/3}+18\cdot \frac23=24.$$